# MVC/Rzor: textbox should show NO value after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In a MVC Form Post scenario, i want to have an empty textbox after the data was posted to the server and the page is again served to the user. Right now, the posted username shows in the the textbox after the postback.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "email", required = "", pattern = "^", @placeholder = "E-mail", @title = "", @id = "UserName", data_hint = "Required"})
}
```

At first, the model containing the username was sent back to the form, so i thought that caused it. I now send back a "clean" model with even a forced empty username but that doesnt help either.

```
return View("SignIn", "_Layout", new ViewModel
{
    UserName = ""
});
```

How do i get an empty textbox after postback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ModelState.Clear()` before setting value. When you post a model back to an ActionResult and return the same View, the values for the model objects are contained in the ModelState.

Then return new Model,

```
ModelState.Clear();
return View("SignIn", "_Layout", new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SignIn", "Account", new AjaxOption{HttpMethod="post", onSuccess="success(data)"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "email", required = "", pattern = "^", @placeholder = "E-mail", @title = "", @id = "UserName", data_hint = "Required"})
}

<script>

function success(data){
    $("#COntrolID").val("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply reload the page after success the call

like

```
 window.location.href = '@Url.Action("SignIn", "_Layout")';
```

This will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There's something about MVC you should know, which is, how does it handle query strings and invoke validation as well as populate the Viewmodel/model...

Answer: On a postback before the controller gets invoked for that action method MVC attempts to do the validation work.  This is why you can use the validation check in the controller before anything else is done!

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
```

But what happens next is confusing until you understand it.  MVC and the browser only deal in Query strings per the HTTP protocol.  So in order for MVC to make strong types, it has to first create a null instance of the model or viewmodel, then it will populate any field in that newly created object with values from the postback that have the same names!

If on returning the posted view you are seeing things you did not expect it simply means the BeginForm logic told MVC what property name is coming back and it told it the value.  This is the only way a posted value is returned in a view using MVC.

If you don't want that value simply exclude it from the post back.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
autocomplete="off"
```

to your textbox

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "email", required = "", pattern = "^", @placeholder = "E-mail", @title = "", @id = "UserName", data_hint = "Required", @autocomplete = "off"})
```